# How to create a new database and tables inside it in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm using T-SQL in order to create a database, and then populate it with tables. The point is that I can create the database successfully, but then when I create the tables it adds them inside the `master` database, not the newly created one. Here is the code segment that I have:

```
USE master;  
GO  
CREATE DATABASE Tester  
ON   
(NAME = Tester_dat,  
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\tester.mdf',  
    SIZE = 10,  
    MAXSIZE = 50,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5)  
LOG ON  
(NAME = Tester_log,  
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\tester.ldf',  
    SIZE = 5MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 25MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB);  
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestCategory](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))
```

I guess the problem might be that I'm using the default schema `[dbo]`, but then again if I replace it with `[Tester]` I get an error saying that the schema doesn't exist. Any idea, how to switch to the newly created database and create the tables inside it?

Comment: How about another `USE` to specify that the table should be created in the new database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `Use`.

```
Use Tester
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestCategory](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))

GO
```

Comment: Oh, just noticed my mistake. I was missing the `GO` after the `USE Tester` statement. Thanks.